# date and time difference not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, php-7, php-5.6

here i want to do employee login time calculation,like

1. My office login time is `2018-02-01 09:30 AM`
2. But my logged in time  `2018-02-01 09:40 AM`

based on above two dates i came to office `10 Mins late`.

suppose my logged in time  `2018-02-01 10:40 AM` **(1 Hr and 20 mins late)**

> My expected results (Mins late means)

```
10 Mins late
```

> My expected results (Hrs late means)

```
1 Hrs late
```

> I tried like this but it is not working properly

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$officeTiming ="2018-02-01 09:30 AM";
$todaymyloginTime ="2018-02-01 09:40 AM";
$datetime1 = date_create($officeTiming);
$datetime2 = date_create($todaymyloginTime);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$suffix = ' Late'; 
    if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) $suffix = ' Before';
    $time_diff= $interval->format('%h:%i:%s'); 
    $start_date = new DateTime($time_diff);
    $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime(date("h:i:s")));
    if(intval($since_start->format('%h')) >= 1){
         $timeago = $since_start->format('%h hours'.$suffix);    
    }
    else if(intval($since_start->format('%i')) >= 1){
         $timeago = $since_start->format('%i minutes'.$suffix);  
    }
    else if(intval($since_start->format('%s')) >= 1){
         $timeago = $since_start->format('%s seconds'.$suffix); 
    }
    echo $timeago;
```

I am getting answer is **4 hours Late** but actually i am **20 mins late**

> My working code

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-02-01 09:30 AM');
 $datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-02-01 09:20 AM');
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 $suffix = ' Late'; 
if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) $suffix = ' Before';

 if($interval->format('%h') ==0){
     echo $interval->format('%i')." Minutes".$suffix;
 }else{
    echo $interval->format('%h')." Hours".$suffix; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be You are looking for this kind of stuff:-

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-02-01 09:30:31 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-02-01 09:40:32 AM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
if($interval->format('%h') ==0){
    echo $interval->format('%i')." Minutes".$interval->format('%s')." Seconds Late";
}else{
    echo $interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes ".$interval->format('%s')." Seconds Late"; 
}
?>
```

Output:-

```
10 Minutes 1 Seconds Late
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No Mr@kunal,Suppose more than 60 mins means automatically it should show 1 hr late or 2 late like that

Comment: Yes it is try it once

Comment: But your code it will not work like that, it will show both `Hrs` and `Min` but this not  correct answer

Comment: @KumaresanM change the date according to your requirement and test it

Comment: Kunal your code working fine , but i need to add one more condition that is `seconds` . like 10 sec late

Comment: Please see top, my working code , in that i want to add `seconds` condition

Comment: It is very simple you need to pass %s to get seconds but you need to pass full datetime :- https://eval.in/947540

Comment: @KumaresanM don't forget to upvote and accept the right answer

Comment: I don't want to print `2 Hours 10 Minutes 5 Seconds Late`, i need less than 60 seconds late means it show like `50 seconds late`,suppose greater than 60 seconds means ,it should show  `10 seconds late` , suppose  greater than 60 Mins means ,it should show  `1 Hours  late`

Comment: That means out of 3 any one functionality should print

Comment: @KumaresanM According to your requirement you can use if else else if conditions. i have give you answer according to your asked question but you have not mentioned this thing in question... You must upvote and accept the answer so i can able to help further

Comment: I accepted answer Mr@ kunal,but unable to make upvote because i don't have enough reputation

Comment: Ok @KumaresanM no issue when you reach at 15 reputation then you can upvote

Answer (score 0):

OK, Programming all of the possible time responses that could come out of this can be a bother, because there are many ways to represent the time interval in between from words like:

*just now, a min ago,* **x** *hours ago,* **y** *days ago*... and so on

There has got to be a better ways to do this right?

Well introducing **Carbon**, a simple PHP API just that allows you to do just that. Here is an example to show you how it works:

If I remember the concept correctly, you first create a file in you project folder called `carbon.php` and and add this.

```
<?php

 namespace Carbon;

 class Carbon extends \DateTime {

 }
```

Then, in your other file, suppose it’s the `index.php` file, you’ll be able to manipute DateTime as how you want with the `diffForHumans()` function.

```
<?php

// index.php

require “Carbon.php”;

$dt_logout = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', '2018-01-30 22:00:00');
$dt_logout2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', '2018-01-02 22:00:00');
$dt_now = Carbon::now();      // Assuming now is 2018-02-02 22:00:00

echo $dt_now->diffForHumans($dt_logout);    // prints 3 days ago
echo $dt_now->diffForHumans($dt_logout2);     // prints 1 month ago
echo $dt_now->diffForHumans($dt_logout2, true);     // prints 1 month

...
```

I hope that was helpful.

Reference:

- http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff